Border Radius Wont Apply to Animated Gradient Border
Im trying to code an animated gradient border, but when I apply border-radius: 5px, it doesn't do anything? I have a feeling it has something to do with border-image but I need that effect to add the gradient animation.
HTML:
<div class="container">
    <div class="animated-border"></div>
    <div class="shadow"></div>
</div>

CSS:
body {
  background: black;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  height: 400px;
}

.animated-border, .shadow {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.animated-border {
  width: 600px;
  height: 400px;
  border: 7px solid;
  border-image: linear-gradient(45deg, #dcadff, #ffade1, #ade8ff, #ffbf80);
  border-image-slice: 1;
  animation: borderAnimation 3s linear infinite;
  background-clip: padding-box, border-box;
}

.shadow {
  width: 600px;
  height: 400px;
  border: 7px solid;
  border-image: linear-gradient(45deg, #dcadff, #ffade1, #ade8ff, #ffbf80);
  border-image-slice: 1;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  animation: borderAnimation 3s linear infinite;
  filter: blur(10px);
  opacity: 80;
}

@keyframes borderAnimation {
  0% {
    border-image-source: linear-gradient(45deg, #dcadff, #ffbf80 #ffade1, #ade8ff);
  }
  50% {
    border-image-source: linear-gradient(405deg, #ade8ff, #dcadff, #ffbf80, #ffade1);
  }
  100% {
    border-image-source: linear-gradient(45deg, #dcadff, #ffade1, #ade8ff, #ffbf80);
  }
}



first duplicate to explain how to have gradient border with radius and second duplicate how to animate gradient
